# Почему не находит элемент?

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
<ul>
        <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
          <li>Example li</li>
        </ul>
```

JS:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');

ul.onclick = function(event) {
    alert();
}
```

`alert` не выводится при клике на элементы `<li>`
Но если присвоить элементу `ul` `id` и искать через `document.getElementById` , то код заработает. Почему так?

Comment: `var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]`

Comment: Почему это работает именно так? Зачем указывать индекс?

Comment: и ещё добавьте : `window.onload = function () {ваш код}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) возвращает коллекцию элементов, которые нашлись в документе. Для доступа к конкретному узлу требуется указать его индекс.

`var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]`

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) же возвращает непосредственно ссылку на искомый узел документа.

Comment: Теперь всё понятно. Спасибо !